# I'm using android studio 3.1.3 and it gives me error whenever I add navigation Drawer Activity and some of the xml files are not working as should be

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create Navigation Drawer Activity, and some xml files are not working and it gives me error like this when I open .xml files..

```
The following classes could not be found:

- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Tip: Try to build the project.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

[v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZTVh.png)

Comment: Have you added related design library dependencies in your build.gradle?

Comment: Nope and I don't know what it is!!!   :)       :(   :(..

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle(Module app) file

Answer (score 0):

change your packages to these packages:

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

also add in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232216/rendering-problem-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Thanks dear bro!!!!!  and now the problems from .java classes resolved but the .xml files are still the same and showing their drawers... please click on   '  v  ' symbol.